# Adding multiple columns from a pandas data frame into a new column

Tags: pandas, list, sum

I ran some code which resulted in either a 1 if something happened or a 0 if it did not.  The results are stored in 8 separate columns (count600, count800, etc) which visual studio has as a list type.  I then added the 8 columns together and have the results appear in a new column titled SUM_OVER90th.  The value stored in the SUM_OVER90th appears like 11111.0 instead of the value 5.  I tried a few different scripts which all seem to give a similar result.  I'm not sure why I'm not able to add these column together.  Thanks for any advice on what I might be doing wrong!

```
COLS_TO_ADD = ['600_COUNT','800_COUNT','1000_COUNT','1200_COUNT','1400_COUNT','1600_COUNT','1800_COUNT','2000_COUNT']
Q_ETL_sub['SUM_OVER90th'] = Q_ETL_sub[COLS_TO_ADD].sum(axis=1)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0avuE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason is that your columns to add are strings, not numbers. You can verify this with

```
Q_ETL_sub.dtypes
```

and if they are not numbers, try convert them into integer with

```
Q_ETL_sub[COLS_TO_ADD] = Q_ETL_sub[COLS_TO_ADD].astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you Raymond, that fixed my issue.  The new column total is now 5!